# Authentication in API Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I new to this and I want to use auth.sentCodee in Python
URL site : https://core.telegram.org/constructor/auth.sentCode

I even try with postman but I still got not found
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1CZr.jpg)

My gold is that I want to get OTP from api instead of going to application or web to send request.

Comment: What  endpoint do you call?

Comment: I sent my request to api.telegram.org

Comment: @Behtash And what does endpoint mean?

Comment: can you send full url that you are sending request, remove all your credentials or api key data if you have set in url.

Comment: Ok let me a second

Comment: HTTPS://api.telegram.org

Comment: https://api.telegram.org/bot<Bot_token>/<method>
For example you can use sentMessage

Comment: I think the problem is about the endpoint or url that you are using something is not correct.

Comment: I really don’t know man I sow a example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63272437/how-can-i-send-a-message-to-someone-with-telegram-api-using-my-own-account and try that

Comment: That's not the bot api, but the mtproto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong documentation. Telegram provides [multiple *API's*](https://core.telegram.org/).

The `auth.sentCode` method you're linking is from the Telegram Core, but you're trying to call it via the [Telegram Bot Api Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

---

> My goal is that I want to get OTP from api instead of going to application or web to send request.

You'll need to [create your own Telegram Application](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id), to be able to read your own chats (so no bots involved). Using a custom application like that allows you to read the Telegram chat in which the OTP code is send.

---

Since you've tagged your question with [python](/questions/tagged/python), I'd suggest taking a look at [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon). A library to interact with Telegram's API **as a user** or through a bot account (bot API alternative).